How to connect VS Code To Jupyter Terminal
Need help connecting to Jupyter Terminal via VSCode IDE.
As of now I am able to connect VS code to jupyter python kernals using jupyterhub, however not sure how to connect to the Terminal so i can access it from within vscode.
JupyterLab v3.6.3
VsCode v1.88
Extension: Jupyterhub
